# Action Script 3. Multiple stages are like 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, stage

I'm creating a simple flash game, where characters move on the groundwith some  stages to jump over.

The problem is all the stages are acting as 1 object, which can make the character appear like it's flying in the air:

[image: on air]

All stages are called: `ground3`
Here is part of code where the character jumps and stay on the ground:

```
if(Hero.y_speed>0 && Hero.hitTestObject(ground3)){
    Hero.y_speed=0;
    if(space){
        trace("You clicked SPACE");
        Hero.y -= 80;
    }
```

Have you any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use external libraries for your purposes, like
[this one](https://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/).

[Here](http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/39-collision-detection-methods-hittest-and-hittestobject-alternatives.html) is described, how to use it (you can find there also other useful informations).

```
import com.coreyoneil.collision.CollisionList;

var myCollisionList:CollisionList = new CollisionList(hero);

//add all stages separately
myCollisionList.addItem(stage[1...n]);

if(myCollisionList.checkCollisions().length > 0) {
     //colision detected
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I need to download any extension from link you gave me? And how can I add these stages? I need save them as different symbols? I mean on every stage I need to click, then convert to symbol and later add to List? And what in this place where //colision detected ?

Comment: Look, that this solution (checking hero collisions with stages separately) has one, big virtue - performance. If hero moves - stages shows up and hide behind the edges of window. If you'd checked hero with all stages at once, you would have done this with stages that dissapeared earlier. In this case, you can add stages to collision list and remove them during the game.

Comment: Yes, you need download source code (download tab) and move it to your source code folder.

Comment: 'I mean on every stage I need to click, then convert to symbol and later add to List?' - Nope, stage should be ONE, COMMON MovieClip for all stages (if you plan add more, different stages types to the game, create new ONE for every type). More info on: http://vimeo.com/9614032‎

Comment: Thank you very much for answers, I downloaded It. So to myCollisionList I need to add only ground3? (ground3 - One, Common MovieClip for all stages). But if I do It I got the same problem, in which function I need to use this code? And what I need to type where you wrote `//colision detected`?

Comment: I see you are starting your adventure with Flash, so I recommend you find and read some tutorials about creating game like this first - you'll see how to do all stuff in proper way.

Comment: By saying ONE I meant one in library (not one MC-parent for all stages), but all stages are copies of the same MC.

Comment: If you want test this collision system, put some stages, name it, add to collisionList (separately). This piece of code:
if(myCollisionList.checkCollisions().length > 0) {
     //colision detected
}
should be in the same place where is your piece of code.

Comment: Ok so I succesfully used It here for y: `if(Hero.y_speed>0 && myList.checkCollisions().length > 0 ){
       Hero.y_speed=0;
    if(space){
    trace("Clicked SPACE");
    Hero.y -= 80;
    }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37274/discussion-between-rimant-baltiejt-and-tomek)